# Suspicious ip address of our mail domain found on talosintelligence.com (spoofing attempt)

Tags: email, dns-spoofing, dnssec

We have a fair amount of email traffic. Recently, we had some suspicious email spoofing attacks and a lot of users reported that outgoing emails were marked as spam and landed in junk folder (reported by mail recipients). When we checked our mail reputation on talosintelligence.com, I found something interesting that I do not fully understand:

Another IP address is listed for our domain "mail-gw33.credit-suisse.com" which does not belong to us.

https://talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=mail-gw33.credit-suisse.com

In addition, I checked https://ipinfo.io/213.209.151.201 and it also points to our hostname.

I have following questions:

- What actually is the meaning of Hostname on talosintelligence.com? Does it mean the suspicious IP address 213.209.151.101 was reverse resolved by other mail relays/hosts? Or was it just sent as SMTP HELO?
- If the IP address 213.209.151.101 was reverse resolved to mail-gw33.credit-suisse.com: how is this even possible? What comes to my mind: DNS hijacking, DNS poisoning
- Does the number "LAST MONTH VOL." on talosintelligence.com mean that the amount of mails were sent successfully using the hostname mail-gw33.credit-suisse.com?
- Can our reputation suffer from hijacking mail-gw33.credit-suisse.com?
- How can we mitigate this in future (e.g. use of DNSSEC for credit-suisse.com)?

[image]

Comment: *"If the IP address 213.209.151.101 was reverse resolved to mail-gw33.credit-suisse.com: how is this even possible?"* - reverse DNS is just setting up a PTR record by the owner of the IP address. Anything can be claimed here, no IP spoofing, DNS hijacking or DNS poisoning needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be from the HELO (or EHLO) string used to identify the sending mail server during the SMTP handshake. It's a decently free-form field and is not really vetted, which is why [FCrDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) is used, but even that isn't a stellar signal.

As a solution, [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) provides a mechanism to note authorization and [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) allows specifying a policy to block forgeries. Still, few people bother to configure SPF for their `HELO` checks, and DMARC far more commonly passes with DKIM and/or SPF's `mail from` check.

The poor reputation of the IP spoofing your domain shouldn't reflect on your IP, though setting up DMARC will make your domain's own reputation more robust against spoofing.

> In addition, I checked https://ipinfo.io/213.209.151.201 and it also points to our hostname.

This is presumably populated by [passive DNS](https://www.spamhaus.com/resource-center/what-is-passive-dns-a-beginners-guide/) (searchable DNS resolver logs), though my own pDNS view doesn't show this association. The IP in question does not have a PTR record (which is what populates rDNS) and the hostname in question resolves solely to your own IP (thus the mismatch).

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not representing Cisco Talos, who happens to be my employer.</sub>